# Pivot On More Than One Column From Source Table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query where pivoting on one column and getting the total notionals works but I also need to get the total notional for another column also (type).

I have tried creating another pivot to show the total for the type column from source table.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT venue, type_, notional FROM ABC ) PIVOT ( SUM(notional) FOR (venue) IN ('A' as A1 , 'B' as B1) ) PIVOT ( SUM(notional) FOR (type_) IN ('Prime') );
```

I expect to see one pivot which would show the total for Prime, A1 and B1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use pivot for this problem, but simple aggregate functions:

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN venue = 'A' THEN notional END) AS venueA
     , SUM(CASE WHEN venue = 'B' THEN notional END) AS venueB
     , SUM(CASE WHEN type_ = 'Prime' THEN notional END) AS Prime
  FROM ABC
```

If it's really only one type you can do the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT venue
         , SUM(CASE WHEN type_ = 'Prime' THEN notional END) over() prime
         , notional 
      FROM ABC ) 
  PIVOT ( SUM(notional) FOR (venue) IN ('A' as A1 , 'B' as B1) )
```

If there is also more then one type you have todo several `PIVOT` queries and then `JOIN` them afterwards:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM (SELECT venue, notional FROM ABC ) 
     PIVOT ( SUM(notional) FOR (venue) IN ('A' as A1 , 'B' as B1) )) 
CROSS JOIN 
   (SELECT * FROM (SELECT type_, notional FROM ABC ) 
     PIVOT ( SUM(notional) FOR (type_) IN ('Prime' AS Prime)))
```

Comment: thank you for the response but the issue is that this is just an example. However in reality I have so many more venue and one type that I'd end up with 20+ case statements. Hence I thought if I can do it in a pivot. Any ideas please?

Comment: can I add a `GROUP BY` so that there are no duplicates in the 1st column which is `COUNTRY`?

For example, `Venue` col and `type_` column belong to a country and when I perform your solution the output is such that there is one row for `Venue` with notionals and then another row for `Type_`. I'd like so see all notionals for `type` and `venue` in one row.

Comment: Yeah just add the column `Country` to both subselects in the 3rd possibility and `JOIN using (country)` instead of `CROSS JOIN`.